# Create Sequence By Using Combination 3 Different Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to generate a sequence number when saving a row in database. This sequence should be
unique by 3 different columns.

| TId | CId | Year | UniqueIdentity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 7 | 2023 | 2023-6-7-1 |
| 6 | 7 | 2023 | 2023-6-7-2 |
| 8 | 7 | 2023 | 2023-8-7-1 |
| 6 | 9 | 2023 | 2023-6-9-1 |
| 6 | 7 | 2024 | 2023-6-7-1 |
| 6 | 7 | 2023 | 2023-6-7-3 |

You can see above the last digit in UniqueIdenity column is only changing when when combination of TId, CId and Year changes.

Currently, I am just using this query,

```
SELECT ISNULL(C, 0) + 1 FORM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM MyTable WHERE TId=@TId AND CId=@CId AND Year=@Year
)
```

But there is concurrency issue using the above.

Comment: You can use `row_number()` window function to process the entire table

Comment: `select *, row_number() over (partition by tid, cid, year)`

Comment: For insertion should I add ROWLOCK,UPDLOCK to avoid concurrency?

Comment: What happens if someone deletes a row, do you need to change all other rows?

Comment: No, I wanna to keep the sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last we used below script,

```
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION [Name]
            SELECT @Seq = COUNT(*) FROM SequencesTable WITH(UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) 
            WHERE [Year]=@Year AND TId=@TId AND CId=@CId;
            
            SET @Seq = ISNULL(@Seq,0) + 1;
                
            INSERT INTO SequencesTable VALUES(@Year, @TId, @CId, @Seq);

        COMMIT TRANSACTION [Name];
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH  
        
        DECLARE @Error int, @Message varchar(4000), @Xstate int;
        SELECT @Error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @Message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @Xstate = XACT_STATE();

         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Name];
         RAISERROR('Name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @Error, @Message);
         
         RETURN;
    END CATCH
```